# Control server side caching by page (Tomcat)?

Tags: caching, tomcat, grails, tomcat6

I'm working with a grails application deployed in tomcat6, and I want to be able to enable or disable server side page caching on a "page by page" basis.  In other words, I want to be able to specify, "Cache page A, but do not cache pages B and C."

Is such a thing possible?  If so, what is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Cache plugin lets you cache controller actions and service method calls, so you could annotate the cacheable pages/actions and leave the ones that shouldn't be cached un-annotated: http://grails.org/plugin/springcache

Comment: While I believe this should work, is there a way for this to be done via Tomcat itself?  The configuring of this needs to be done "post-deployment", so in my case I don't believe this solution is viable. :/.